# how to setup svnserve <svn://> protocol for subversion repositories?

Tags: svn, fisheye

We are facing some timeout issue in fisheye - svn repositories. We are using https:// protocol for Subversion. So we are thinking this might be causing the issue. We want to setup svn:// protocol for better indexing in fisheye. How could we setup svnserve for our subversion repositories?

NOTE: we are using a shared drive (NASH Drive) for Subversion repositories.

Comment: What errors do you receive in fisheye?

Answer (score 0):

Subversion will allow only one protocol to use at a time either http:// or svn://

http:// protocol is fine to use with Crucible/fisheye indexing , increase timeout in crucible accordingly for indexing to complete.

How big is the SVN repo ?

To run svn:// . subversion to be run as a daemon

Comment: Hi Anil, We have more than 150 repositories are there in subversion and 10+ repositories are having 20+GB in size. Yeah we have ran svn:// protocol in deamon mode but that is causing issue when ever we restarted server. So, is it a way that we can run that svn:// protocol should be run as a service.

Comment: Only daemon mode is possible for svn:// protocol. what svn version is used ? upgrade to 1.10 latest after dumping and restoring will reduce size of repos too.May be this will help.